# creating a global variable that is assigned within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to ng-click assign a variable (success) inside an ng-repeat and then use that value outside of the ng-repeat(failure) as follows:

```
    <div class="stocksNav col s1">
      <div class="myStockList" ng-repeat="stocksInPortfolio in ctrl.myPortfolio.stocksInPortfolio">
        <ul>
          <li style="position: relative"><a href ng-click="ctrl.tab = stocksInPortfolio.stock._id">{{stocksInPortfolio.stock.name | limitTo:10}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      <div class="myStockView" ng-show="ctrl.tab === stocksInPortfolio.stock._id">
        <div class="{ active:ctrl.tab === stocksInPortfolio.stock._id }">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-include="'/app/dashboard/partials/myIndividualStock.html'"></div>
```

the partial wants to then call ctrl.tab to use it's click event assigned values, such that if i ng-click on any other instance of the ng-repeat function the ctrl.tab variable will reassign, but the ctrl.tab assignment does not persist outside of the ng-repeat div.  any thought?

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-repeat` directive (as many other directives) creates a new scope, and to access a parent's scope variable, it needs to be an object. In other words, instead of `ctrl.tab`, initialize a object `$scope.something = {}` in your controller, then use `ctrl.something.tab` in your template (replace `something` with a name proper to your application).

Comment: i think my question was a little un clear but i have solved it already thanks!